# IEnumerable<IEnumerable>> and Extension Method

Tags: c#, ienumerable, extension-methods

I was wondering if someone could help me understand the following behavior. In the following code, I am creating a `CustomObject` instance, which contains a single Property of type `IEnumerable<IEnunumerable>>`.

I also have an extension Method on `IEnumerable<T>` called `AsDataTable`.

```
public class CustomObject
{
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable> Collection {get;set;}
}


public static class ExtensionMethods
{

public static bool AsDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)

{
    Console.Write("In extension method");
    return default(bool);
}
}

void Main()
{

    var ttObject = new CustomObject()
    {
        Collection = new List<IEnumerable>
        {
            new List<int>{1,2,3},
            new [] {new{A="abc",B="def"}}
        } 
    };
    var dummy = new []{new {a='r'}}.AsDataTable();

    foreach(var item in ttObject.Collection)
    {
        var temp = item.AsDataTable();
        Console.WriteLine($"Item is IEnumerable : {item is IEnumerable}");
    }
}
```

What makes me wonder if the following line of code works (or rather compiles)

```
var dummy = new []{new {a='r',b='3'}}.AsDataTable();
```

while when I loop over the Collection Property of `CustomObject` and then do the same it doesn't allow me to compile.

```
var temp = item.AsDataTable(); // this doesn't work
```

Curiously the following line returns true reconfirming 'item' is indeed `IEnumerable`.

```
 Console.WriteLine($"Item is IEnumerable : {item is IEnumerable}");
```

I guess it is because the extension method is written over Generic version `IEnumerable<T>`, but then how is it that it works over the anonymous type array (outside the `CustomObject`).

Comment: what you want to do in this method "AsDataTable". var temp = item.AsDataTable (); // this doesn't work anyway. you defined it as a list extension

Comment: As the name suggest, I intend to create a DataTable from IEnumerable of anonymous types. For the sake of example, I had removed the code.

Comment: public static bool AsDataTable(this IEnumerable item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable`, not vice versa.

Through a bit of runtime hacking, `SomeType[]` actually does implement `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. On the other hand, `IEnumerable` doesn't - and overload resolution is done at compile time, so the compiler has no idea that your `IEnumerable` items in the collection actually also implement `IEnumerable<int>`.

If you need to work with `IEnumerable`, you need to use that in your extension method.